# Getting data from Firebase with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am having error in getting data from Firebase:

> Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 6 found. Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named)

I am sending six values to Firebase successfully, but it is not allowing me to get the values. I am using realtime database.

```
 List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [];

  bool _showChart = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();

    DatabaseReference transactionRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Transactions");

    transactionRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var KEYS = snap.value.keys; 
      var DATA = snap.value; 

      _userTransactions.clear(); 

     for(var individualKey in KEYS)
      {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction
        (
          DATA[individualKey]['id'], 
          DATA[individualKey]['title'], 
          DATA[individualKey]['amount'],
          DATA[individualKey]['date'],
          DATA[individualKey]['color'], 
          DATA[individualKey]['picker'],   

        ); 

      _userTransactions.add(transaction); 
      }
      setState(() {
        print('Length: $_userTransactions.length'); 

      });

    });
  }
```

Comment: This is the message that I am getting                                                                               ''Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 6 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.dart(extra_positional_arguments_could_be_named)''

Comment: Apparently, `Transaction()` constructor expects 0 arguments

Comment: It would help us if you include the error stacktrace.